# Dynamic UI via MVVM Pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm building MVVM based wpf application and i'm facing some problem :
I need to build the UI based on information that comes from the model,for example
My model holds a list of processes (loads from XML file - dynamic) ,each process contains information (name,icon path ,etc..)
foreach process i need to build a single button (that displays the correspands process info) ,in order to do that i need to retrieve the list of processes from the viewModel to the UI (in order to execute the actual UI build),that will force The UI to reference the processes container...and will break the MVVM .

someone have any idea how to implement this without breaking the MVVM ??

Many Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to use MVVM for every scenario.  The event driven model is sometimes better for certain cases.  Checkout this forum post http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/127825.aspx  Read where Laurent R. talks about MVVM.  He's the guy that makes MVVM Toolkit.  Anyway, sorry it's not an answer, but just giving you a heads up. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` bound to a collection on the ViewModel. Within the `ItemsControl` define a `DataTemplate` which will essentially be a wrapper around building your `Button` based on each process.

```
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Content="{Binding ProcessName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do more than just change the text in the button, you could use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)